# Is it possible to get local username from python/batch when running as admin?

Tags: python, batch-file

I am running a python code to restrict file access using acl. To restrict local user acl, I need username of local user from a code running as another admin user.
Is it possible to get it by de elevating the code or so

Edit:
 I am logged in as local user but the python code run as an admin user. I need to obtain current logged in user but since the code is running as admin i get the admin user when os.getlogin(),socket.fqdn(),os.environ are used.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You have tagged also batch file. Do you want to get username through batch file or python. Also, are you logged in as local or admin user? Please edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

The user name does not change when running as admin if you are an admin.

So,

```
echo %username%
```

Comment: check before you give answer - when run as an admin user you get the admins user name not the local user name